# passing vb parameters to batch file

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I am trying to carry out next batch file:

```
route ADD 131.1.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 191.168.0.136
pause
```

However, I would like to make the ip addresses variable by a visual basic app.

Now I tried next:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim a

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        a = (TextBox1.Text)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim objWshShell
        objWshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objWshShell.run(Chr(34) & "C:\NAT\RouteHCM.bat" & Chr(34) & a, 1)

    End Sub
End Class
```

How can I add more variables and is it possible to make this batch script ( add route in visual basic directly) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

- assume you have TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3 on the form
- replace the entire class with the following:

```vb
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        With New Process()
            .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            .StartInfo.FileName = "route"
            .StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-p add {0} mask {1} {2}",
                                                 TextBox1.Text,
                                                 TextBox2.Text,
                                                 TextBox3.Text)
            .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Text.Encoding.ASCII
            .Start()
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you check help for [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`StartInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), you will get the idea. (I'm learning things from there, too.)

Comment: How could i make this with a vb script? Without using this batch file... Add route

Comment: @Joep – Even if I check [MSDN Q&A](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de500ec3-c0fc-411a-a21d-6917bede9b80/route-add-with-c?forum=netfxnetcom), they are doing it the same way as above – calling shell command. And did you mean [tag:vb.net] or [tag:vbscript]? They are two different languages and technologies.